# mschart zoom and scroll

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, jqplot

This must be a stupid question but i'm kind of stuck in it. I need to display 6000+ records on a mschart using c# for a web application. But he issue is it displays without spaces, but this is unacceptable because i want to see the seperate columns for each recors. I browsed through many solutions provided online but that does not apply to my issue, I tried,

```
//Set automatic zooming
chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;

// Set automatic scrolling 
chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].CursorX.AutoScroll = true;
chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].CursorY.AutoScroll = true;
```

But the AxisX, AxisY commands gives an error saying that is not available. please help me i tried everything i can but it doesnt work. i even tried this,

http://nuget.org/packages/MSChartExtension

eventhough it is for windows forms, but no luck..please help me.. I appreciate it very much. :)

EDIT: This is the code i came up with after the reference..but it doesnt display anything :( i am a noob at this please help :)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.jqplot.css" />
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div>

        </div>
               <div id="chartdiv" style="height:400px;width:300px; ">
               <!--[if lt IE 9]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
               <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
               <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>

               <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

                     $.jqplot('chartdiv', [[[1, 2], [3, 5.12], [5, 13.1], [7, 33.6], [9, 85.9], [11, 219.9]]]);
               </script>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and i put all the javascripts that i downloaded from here to my project folder which is,
C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite1 .. please correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are still in beginning of development, i would strongly recommend using [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/)
as it has got many options and great visual effects. It is also very easy to use with ASP.NET.

**EDIT:**
it seems from your code that you forgot to add references to the script files as mentioned [here](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html)

you should add these in the `<head></head>` of your page:(change **src** as location of files in your project)

```
 <!--[if lt IE 9]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.jqplot.css" />
```

Comment: okey...yeaaa..i am still at the begining of development..thank you very much..i will check this out :)

Comment: hey..i took a look at jqPlot n ts pretty cool..but i cudnt get anything to my web page after trying the given examples.can you please be so kind to help on this...any example codes with asp.net or links would be really great :)

Comment: just to get me started on creating the graphs :)

Comment: sure .. i have used it in one of my recent projects .. go to this link .. it has in detailed discussed how to use it - step by step. if you still face any difficulty, contact me.

http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html

Comment: hey...i tried to display a line chart..but it returned nothing i updated my question with the code i made..i am using asp.net c# webforms :)

Comment: hey thank you very much for helping me out. this graph is one of the important features of the project i am working on :)

Comment: Oh yea...totally forgot about it, Thank you very much for pointing that out :) :)